# Field isn't instantiated before use

Tags: java

The following code, when run, results in a NullPointerExecption. (`Option` superclass omitted for brevity, you can find it [here](https://dpaste.com/DE57N6NKA))

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Option option;

        while (true) {
            option = CommunicationOption.HELLO.prompt();  // NullPointerException
            if (CommunicationOption.HELLO.equals(option)) {
                System.out.println("Hello, world!");
            } else if (CommunicationOption.CONVERSE.equals(option)) {
               // ...
            } else if (CommunicationOption.BYE.equals(option)) {
                System.out.println("Goodbye, world!");
            } else if (CommunicationOption.QUIT.equals(option)) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    static class CommunicationOption extends Option {
        public static final CommunicationOption HELLO    = new CommunicationOption(1, "Say hello");
        public static final CommunicationOption CONVERSE = new CommunicationOption(2, "Start conversation");
        public static final CommunicationOption BYE      = new CommunicationOption(3, "Say goodbye");
        public static final CommunicationOption QUIT     = new CommunicationOption(0, "Quit");

        private static final ArrayList<Option> instances = new ArrayList<>(4);

        CommunicationOption(int id, String label) {
            super(id, label);
            
            instances.add(this);
        }

        @Override
        public Option prompt() {
            return prompt(instances); // Option prompt(Collection<Option>) from superclass.
        }
    }
}
```

Stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at xyz.portal2d.OptionLibrary.Option.prompt(Option.java:20)
    at xyz.portal2d.OptionLibrary.Main$CommunicationOption.prompt(Main.java:57)
    at xyz.portal2d.OptionLibrary.Main.main(Main.java:11)
```

The issue occurs in the constructor of `CommunicationOption`. I attempt to add the recently constructed object into the `instances`, however, `instances` hasn't been instantiated by Java, so a NullPointerExecption shows up.

I've tried to edit the constructor to catch this bug, like so:

```
private static ArrayList<Option> instances = new ArrayList<>(4);

CommunicationOption(int id, String label) {
    super(id, label);
            
    if ( instances == null ) {
        instances = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    instances.add(this);
}
```

The execption no longer throws, however, `instances` gets instantiated again and ends up pointing to a different place in memory when `prompt()` gets called. If I make `instances` null, `instances` ends up being null when `prompt()` is run.

Ideally, it would be great if I could tell Java to instance a field immediately at runtime, however, I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Where is your stack trace? What line throws the NullPointerException? The stack trace should tell you precisely the location.

Comment: Your constructor will always have `this` be `null` in the middle of instantiation.  Once the constructor completes instantiation, *then* it will be able to do something with an instance of a class.  The logic to keep track of instances of `CommunicationOption` can't live in the same class.

Comment: @Makoto - that is not true.  I expect you can recall examples where instance variables are assigned from constructor parameters, via lines of the form `this.foo = foo` in a constructor definition.  This wouldn't work if `this` were `null` in the constructor.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I've added the stack trace, however, I've already explained how the `NullPointerException` appears, based on the information I've gathered with my debugger.

Comment: @Makoto Then I'd expect `instances` to be full of `null`, but `instances` itself is null until `prompt()` is run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`static` fields will be initialized in the order they occur in the source code.

Your `HELLO`/... fields are before your `instances` field so when the initializer for the former fields are executed the later one will not have been initialized.

Simply move the `instances` field *before`the other`public static final` fields.

Alternatively, you can make this all much more explicit, by moving the initialization of these fields to a `static` block a little like this:

```
static {
  HELLO    = new CommunicationOption(1, "Say hello");
  CONVERSE = new CommunicationOption(2, "Start conversation");
  BYE      = new CommunicationOption(3, "Say goodbye");
  QUIT     = new CommunicationOption(0, "Quit");
  instances = List.of(HELLO, CONVERSE, BYE, QUIT);
}
```

Another alternative would be to turn your `CommunicationOption` class into an `enum`. This would imply chaning `Option` into an interface, since `enum` classes can't have explicit base classes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private static final ArrayList<Option> instances = new ArrayList<>(4);

public static final CommunicationOption HELLO    = new CommunicationOption(1, "Say hello");
public static final CommunicationOption CONVERSE = new CommunicationOption(2, "Start conversation");
public static final CommunicationOption BYE      = new CommunicationOption(3, "Say goodbye");
public static final CommunicationOption QUIT     = new CommunicationOption(0, "Quit");
```

you need to initialize the ArrayList before you can initialize `HELLO`